# Should testing, Javascript webservice API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mocha.js

I am testing my REST API with should.

At the moment i have tested my methods to work as intended via the browser, and console testing.

My test cases are turning out to work just fine when testing with should, on the GET methods from my API.

Are there any way to test the delete and post methods in should, og would i be better of to use another testing enviroment ? 
Following is a snippet from my API

```
router.delete('/deleteProfile/:id', function (req, res) { 
var toDelete = req.params.id;
dataLayer.deleteProfile(toDelete, function (err, result) {
    if(err) res.status(500).send('Person + ' + toDelete+ ' not deleted')
    else{
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);

    }
});
```

Following is a snippet of my test :

```
it("Should delete the user With the userName FrækFyr91", function (done) {
    http.get("http://localhost:"+testPort+"/profileApi/deleteProfile/FrækFyr91",function(res){
        res.setEncoding("utf8");//response data is now a string
        res.on("data",function(chunk){
            var n = JSON.parse(chunk);
            n.length.should.equal(4);
            done();
        });
    })
});
```

I know the http.delete wont work.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using http, I'd recommend using one of the specialized REST client libs, like [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler), which are specifically designed to communicate with RESTful routes.

You might also consider using [chai](http://chaijs.com/) for your testing assertions as it provides very comprehensive BDD-style assertions.

So instead of your:

```
http.get(endpointUrl,function(res){
  res.on('data',...);
});
```

I'd use:

```
var mocha=require('mocha'),
    should=require('chai').should(),
    client=require('restler');

describe('deletions',function(){

  it('should delete something',function(done){

    client.del(deleteEndpointUrl).on('complete',function(result){

      // if the request failed, result will be an Error
      if(result instanceof Error) {
        return done(result); // return error
      }

      // test result here

      result.should.be.an.object; // chai.should extends objects with assertions

      // etc.

      done();

    });

  });

});
```